# Grammar question ~そうとしない

Tags: grammar

I was reading this sentences, and I've come across a grammar structure I am not familiar with:

~そうとしない

Original sentence:

春江は泣いてばかりいて何も話そうとしない。
Harue is just crying and won't talk about anything.

I am assuming from the context it must mean something along the lines of "won't do ~" but I've never seen it before.

If someone could explain this to me and perhaps show me some example sentences showing its usage that would be great.

Specifically hoping for some examples using ない which don't appear in other previously answered questions.

Comment: 話そう is the volitional form of 話す.